# How can I display all the elements stored in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

Consider:

```
class vehicle{
private:
    vector<string>carList;
public:
    void info();
    void displayCarInfo(vector<string>&carList);
}

void vehicle::info(){
    char a;
    string choice;
    do{
        cout<<"Please enter your car Reg number: ";
        cin >> carPlate;
        carList.push_back(carPlate);
        cout << "Do you want to continue add car info(y/n)?";
        cin >> choice;
    }while(choice == "y");
}

void vehicle::displayCarInfo(vector<string>&carList){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        cout << carList[i];
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){
    vehicle a;
    a.displayCarInfo(carList);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Errors are shown when displaying all the car list. How can I solve it?
2. And how can I retrieve information for a particular element inside `carList`?

Comment: [This `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) might come in handy. Also note that there are three typical ways to loop (iterate) over containers using `for` loops: Using size, using iterators and using [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), and any decent tutorial or book should have shown you at least two of these ways.

Comment: Hi, can i know where i need to do modify on the code?Any wrong syntax for a.displayCarInfo(carList); inside int main?

Comment: The syntax is correct, but what if there is not 100 elements in the vector? Then you go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. *Do* some searching and reading on your own!

Comment: Have you even compiled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to pass the vector as an argument to `void displayCarInfo();`:

   ```
    class Vehicle{ //<--- define classes starting with uppercase 
    private:
       vector<string>carList;
    public:
        void info();
        void displayCarInfo();
    }; //<----- you need a semicolon here
   ```
2. The termination condition should be the vector size.

   ```
    void vehicle::displayCarInfo() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < carList.size();  ++i) {
            cout << carList[i];
        }
    }
   ```

In `main()`:

```
  int main(){
      vehicle a;
      a.displayCarInfo();
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Something seems to be missing in *"The in the"*.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the `<iostream>` and `<vector>` header files were included, the program has so many compilation errors. Did you not check those?

Like: `choice` and `carPlate` was never declared. Class declaration doesn't end with a `;`, etc.

Issues:

1. You create a vehicle `a` and never put anything in the member variables. I guess the `info()` function was supposed to do that; then why wasn't it called? I guess you'd need to do that in some loop.
2. You made the `carList` vector private and tried to pass the same as an argument from `main()` to the `displayCarInfo()` function. I hope you realize that such a thing won't be required as being a member function of that same class it can access the `carList` directly. You simply need to call the public function using an object.
3. Since *vectors* are unbounded (meaning their range can grow and shrink), it's not a good idea to print the content of an vector using a constant loop. That way you always risk a chance of either overrunning the loop or under-running it.

   Instead, prefer

   ```
   for (auto const& car: carList) {
        std::cout << car << '\n';
   }
   ```

Although there are smarter ways to do the same using `std::ostream_iterator`s and `std::copy()`, but that can rest for now.

Comment: I hope you realize, while changing the function call. You'd also need to change the function definition. I am sorry to say, but this is plain spoon feeding and won't help you. Before trying to get to classes, first go through the basics of the language.